# Accessibility footnote error

Tags: luatex, accessibility, tagged-pdf, tagpdf

When we run the **Accessibility Full Check** in Acrobat DC or Acrobat Professional. We getting the below error for footnote. I'm running the file through LuaLaTeX TeXLive2022 and upgraded the tagged pdf package. How to solve this issue.

[image]

MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{testphase=phase-II}

\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Testing}

\section{Introduction}
In a nutshell, the following key attributes of the doctrine are discernible from the case law:
\begin{enumerate}
\item fair use is `an affirmative defense requiring a case-by-case analysis';\footnote{\textit{Harper \& Row} at 561; \textit{Campbell} at 577.}

\item because fair use of copyrighted material is seen `to fulfil copyright's very purpose [to promote the Progress of Science and useful Arts]',\footnote{\textit{Campbell} at 575, citing Art I, {\textsection} 8, cl 8 of the US Constitution.} the application of the doctrine `requires judicial balancing'\footnote{\textit{Google} at 1197.} `between creativity and availability';\footnote{\textit{Andy Warhol Foundation for the Visual Arts, Inc v Goldsmith} No. 21--869; 143 S Ct 1258 (2023) (`\textit{Goldsmith}') (slip op.) at p 13.}

\item accordingly, fair use is a `flexible' concept, whose `application may well vary depending upon context'.\footnote{\textit{Google} at 1197. The fair use exception has been described as providing `considerable flexibility': Pamela Samuelson, `Unbundling Fair Uses' (2009) 77 \textit{Fordham Law Review} 2537 at 2540.}

\end{enumerate}

Section~107 sets out a non-exhaustive list of fair use or fairness `factors', and the illustrative examples of fair use provided in the preamble likewise do not constitute a closed list.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are using `phase-II`, but `phase-III` is the current situation: this is developmental code and you really need to be using the latest release

Comment: I tried in phase-III also but the error not rectified.

Answer (score 4):

You really should keep your system up-to-date if you want to make your document accessible. TeXlive 2022 is too old!

But beside this: it is a bug in the acrobat checker. Even with a up-to-date system Acrobat will complain about the following document as it doesn't accept that the `Lbl` tag is used outside a list for the number of the section (which is quite valid!).  So complain to adobe, they should correct that in their test.

```
\DocumentMetadata{testphase=phase-III,pdfstandard=ua-1}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftitle=Testing,pdfdisplaydoctitle}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Testing}

\section{Introduction}

In a nutshell
\end{document}
```

[image]