# Tagpdf Creation using lualatex-dev (Section should be H1 tag)

Tags: luatex, tagged-pdf, tagpdf

I would like to get `Tagged PDF` from `LaTeX` file using `LuaLaTeX-Dev`. Output Tagged PDF is created successfully, but how to `change/delete` unwanted tag `PART`? Refer below screenshot:

[image]

LaTeX Kernel Ver is : `LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> pre-release-0 (develop 2024-2-14 branch) and L3 programming layer <2024-01-22>`

TagPDF Version is : `2024-02-04 v0.98v`

Lua and MikTeX is : `This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.1 (MiKTeX 24.1)`

My MWE is:

```
\DocumentMetadata{testphase=phase-II,pdfstandard=UA-1,pdfversion=1.7,uncompress}

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphics,amsmath}

\usepackage{hyperxmp,array}

\usepackage[pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 0},bookmarksnumbered,bookmarksopen=true,colorlinks,%
    linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,%
    linktoc=none, pdfview={XYZ null null 1.00}]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    
\chapter{Chapter Title Here}

\section{Introduction}\label{S1}

In total, 37.7{\%} of respondents (49.4{\%}. This study's objective was to
remove barriers to employment for PwCD through inclusive design of
technology supports in warehouses and similar settings.
Specifically, a nonlinear context-aware prompting system (NCAPS) was
developed, iteratively refined, and tested.

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Distribution of Participant Characteristics}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lclr}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Participant}} & \textbf{Age} & \textbf{Gender} & \textbf{Diagnosis}\\
\hline
\textbf{P01} & 28 & F & Cerebral Palsy\\
\textbf{P02} & 25 & M & Autism Spectrum Disorder\\
\textbf{P03} & --- & M & Autism Spectrum Disorder\\
\textbf{P04} & 38 & F & IDD (unspecified)\\
\textbf{P05} & 25 & M & Cerebral Palsy\\
\textbf{P06} & 23 & M & Down Syndrome\\
\textbf{P07} & 19 & M & IDD (unspecified)\\
\hline
\end{tabular}{}
\end{table}


In a pilot crossover
study, subjects with cognitive disabilities participated in
simulated work sessions, picking orders in a small warehouse
environment using the NCAPS and industry-standard paper tickets.
Their performance was assessed in terms of errors and productivity,
and their insights and perspectives were gathered. The resulting
NCAPS prevented or corrected all errors for all but one participant.
It also increased productivity for participants with the poorest
baseline (paper ticket) performance, but decreased productivity for
those with high baseline performance. 
    
\begin{figure}[b]
%\includegraphics[alt={Figure 1}]{image.png}
\caption{Structure of NCAPS implementation.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Table is not tagged proberly (TR, TD tags...) How to get the expected tagged PDF?

Comment: unrelated but be aware that [h] is seldom a good idea. It does *not* force the table to stay, but only restricts placement options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `phase-III` for the tagging of section commands, and the `table` module for basic table tagging.
You then also should tell the code that the first line is a header row (be aware that the table module currently doesn't support header columns). So start with this

```
\DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III,table},pdfstandard=UA-1,pdfversion=1.7,uncompress}
\tagpdfsetup{table-header-rows=1} % \tagpdfsetup{table/header-rows=1} in next latex-dev
```

Remarks:

- `hyperxmp`: hyperxmp is not compatible. The tagging code will suppress it, so its commands and settings will be ignored.
- `uncompress`: that is only needed for debugging and can make the pdf much larger.
- The next LaTeX-dev (that was released today) will contain support for `\maketitle` (you need to load the title module) and for `\marginpar` and various bug-fixes. I therefore recommend to use lualatex-dev for compilation (I don't know when miktex will get it, in texlive it should be in one or two days).
- The new title module will also set the title text as window title, but until then you should use for UA-1 the hyperref option `pdfdisplaydoctitle`.

Comment: Not `Table` is tagged correct. Thanks. But its showing `Failed` when checking with `Adobe`. Please refer screenshot is attached.

Comment: please do not edit question to append new questions. That only makes answer invalid and makes it harder to follow. Ask a new questions.

Comment: That is not a new question. As per your changes LaTeX Code, it is showing error used `Adobe Acrobat Accessibility Checker`.

Comment: yes it is a new question, as it is about how the accessibility checker works (which doesn't get everything right, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703383/2388).  So if you want an answer from me about it you should ask a new question, I won't edit this one.

Comment: New question is <https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/709651/tagged-pdf-creation-with-lualatex-dev-adobe-acrobat-profession-error> and how to fix this?