# Tagged PDF creation with lualatex-dev (Adobe Acrobat Profession Error)

Tags: luatex, tagged-pdf, tagpdf

The below `LaTeX` code compile without Any errors and created Tagged-PDF.

LaTeX Kernel Ver is : `LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> pre-release-0 (develop 2024-2-15 branch) and L3 programming layer <2024-01-22>`

TagPDF Version is : `2024-02-04 v0.98v`

Lua and MikTeX is : `This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.1 (MiKTeX 24.1)`

My MWE Is:

```
\DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III,table},pdfstandard=UA-1,pdfversion=1.7,uncompress}
\tagpdfsetup{table-header-rows=1}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,graphics,amsmath,hyperxmp,array}
\usepackage[pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 0},bookmarksnumbered,bookmarksopen=true,colorlinks,%
    linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,%
    linktoc=none, pdfview={XYZ null null 1.00}]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftitle=Chapter Title Here,pdfdisplaydoctitle}

\begin{document}
    
\title{Chapter Title Here}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}\label{S1}

In total, 37.7{\%} of respondents (49.4{\%}. This study's objective was to
remove barriers to employment for PwCD through inclusive design of
technology supports in warehouses and similar settings.
Specifically, a nonlinear context-aware prompting system (NCAPS) was
developed, iteratively refined, and tested.

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Distribution of Participant Characteristics}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lclr}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Participant}} & \textbf{Age} & \textbf{Gender} & \textbf{Diagnosis}\\
\hline
\textbf{P01} & 28 & F & Cerebral Palsy\\
\textbf{P02} & 25 & M & Autism Spectrum Disorder\\
\textbf{P03} & --- & M & Autism Spectrum Disorder\\
\textbf{P04} & 38 & F & IDD (unspecified)\\
\textbf{P05} & 25 & M & Cerebral Palsy\\
\textbf{P06} & 23 & M & Down Syndrome\\
\textbf{P07} & 19 & M & IDD (unspecified)\\
\hline
\end{tabular}{}
\end{table}


In a pilot crossover
study, subjects with cognitive disabilities participated in
simulated work sessions, picking orders in a small warehouse
environment using the NCAPS and industry-standard paper tickets.
Their performance was assessed in terms of errors and productivity,
and their insights and perspectives were gathered. The resulting
NCAPS prevented or corrected all errors for all but one participant.
It also increased productivity for participants with the poorest
baseline (paper ticket) performance, but decreased productivity for
those with high baseline performance. 
    
\begin{figure}[b]
%\includegraphics[alt={Figure Caption}]{graph18.png}
\caption{Structure of NCAPS implementation.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But `Adobe Accessibility Checker` showing `Failed` (maketitle, Table and Label).

I have checked [Accessibility footnote error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/703381/accessibility-footnote-error/703383#703383) (Need bugs to send adobe).

Please refer below screen-shot.

[image]

How to solve this Error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At first: Do not trust every failure message. Validators have bugs and sometimes complain about perfectly fine documents. I would recommend to use as validator verapdf (https://dev.verapdf-rest.duallab.com). Imho it is currently the most reliable and up-to-date validator, and if it has a bug such bugs are normally fixed rather fast.

1. To get a better tagging of the `\maketitle` you need the new title module, which just (yesterday) has been released in the newest latex-dev. If you have that you can use
   `testphase={phase-III,table,title}` and then must compile with `lualatex-dev`.
2. The Lbl error is due to a fault in the acrobat validator. It complains that Lbl is used outside list. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703383/2388.
   We will probably rename the tag to get around this Acrobat bug but this will take some time, perhaps at the next release.
3. I do not get an error at the table, only a warning as Acrobat checks if the (optional) summary attribute exists:

   [image]

   Such a summary is currently not supported. It is quite unclear what use it has (if any) and what content it should have. The PDF spec is quite vage, and I doubt very much that there is some tool which needs it.

[image]

4. In the verapdf checker the document passes (with the title module) without problems:

[image]

5. In PAC 2024 (https://pac.pdf-accessibility.org/en) it fails on the table. This failure is wrong too: PAC 2024 seems not to be able to process attribute classes.

Comment: Where can i see the `\DocumentMetadata{testphase` value options and documentation (like title, table)?.

Comment: texdoc documentmetadata-support (but I missed to add the title option, I will correct that later ...). You can also check the modules in latex-lab. Anyone can be loaded with a testphase-key.