# Tagged PDF Creating Using Table Module -- Error

Tags: luatex, tagged-pdf, tagpdf

I have created `Tagged PDF` as per this lin [Tagged PDF creation with lualatex-dev (Adobe Acrobat Profession Error)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/709651/tagged-pdf-creation-with-lualatex-dev-adobe-acrobat-profession-error). It's showing `Adobe Acroabt Profeesional` and `PAC-2024` Showing Error. It is Bug? or/and how to solve this?

**NOTE:** In `table body`

\arrayrulecolor{green}\hline     %%%%   It's Working

{\arrayrulecolor{green}\hline} %%%%  It's Not Working When Grouping

My Mwe is:

```
\DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III,title,table},pdfversion=1.7,uncompress}
\tagpdfsetup{table-header-rows=1}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec,colortbl,amsmath,hyperxmp,array}
\usepackage[pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 0},bookmarksnumbered,bookmarksopen=true,colorlinks,    linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,linktoc=none, pdfview={XYZ null null 1.00}]{hyperref}

\hypersetup{pdftitle=Article Title,pdfdisplaydoctitle}

\begin{document}
\title[Helping or Hindering]{Helping or Hindering: Inclusive Design of Automated Task Prompting}

\author{{GAVIN R.} {PHILIPS}}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Of the $\sim$8.8 million working-age adults with cognitive
disabilities in the United States, only 28.6\% are employed,
contributing to a poverty rate (26.1\%).
\end{abstract}



\section{Introduction}\label{S1}

In total, 37.7{\%} of respondents (49.4{\%}. This study's objective was to
remove barriers to employment for PwCD through inclusive design of
technology supports in warehouses and similar settings.

\begin{enumerate}
\item[{(1)}] Between the ages of 18 and 65 years
\item[{(2)}] Cognitive disability as determined by the State of Colorado Office of Disability
\item[{(3)}] Fine motor skills within gross normal limits
\end{enumerate}


\begin{table}
{\caption{Distribution of Participant Characteristics}}
{
\begin{tabular}{l!{\color{green}\vrule}lll}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Participant}} & \textbf{Age} & \textbf{Gender} & \textbf{Diagnosis}\\
\arrayrulecolor{green}\hline%%%% It's Working
%{\arrayrulecolor{green}\hline}%%%% It's Not Working When Grouping
\textbf{P01} & 28 & F & Cerebral Palsy\\[5pt]
\textbf{P02} & 25 & M & Autism Spectrum Disorder\\[5pt]
\textbf{P03} & --- & M & Autism Spectrum Disorder\\[5pt]
\textbf{P04} & 38 & F & IDD (unspecified)\\[5pt]
\textbf{P05} & 25 & M & Cerebral Palsy\\[5pt]
\textbf{P06} & 23 & M & Down Syndrome\\[5pt]
\textbf{P07} & 19 & M & IDD (unspecified)\\[3pt]
\hline
\end{tabular}}{}
\end{table}

In a pilot crossover
study, subjects with cognitive disabilities participated in
simulated work sessions. 

\end{document}
```

Please find the screenshot below:

[image]

`LuaLaTeX` ::: `This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.0 (TeX Live 2023)`

`LaTeX2e`  ::: `LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> pre-release-1 (develop 2024-2-20 branch)`

`L3`       ::: `L3 programming layer <2024-02-18>`

Terminal/Command Prompt : `lualatex-dev filename.tex`

Comment: What is your question? 1. Why do I get an error in the tag structure, as ca be seen in the screenshot -- OR: -- 2. Why do I get an error using `{\arrayrulecolor{green}\hline}`?

Comment: @KeksDose: When compiling it's not showing any error. When checking the PDF using `Adobe Acrobat Pro` or `PAC-2024` it's showing `tagged structure` issues (attached screenshot is adobe-acrobat-pro issues). Without `{}` `\arrayrulecolor{green}\hline` you will not get error when creating tagged PDF, With `{}` `{\arrayrulecolor{green}\hline}` get error. Maybe bugs in `Tagged Package`???

Comment: do not load the colortbl package. It is currently not a compatible package. It redefines tabular commands and break the tagging. And as I already told you, do not load hyperxmp.

Comment: More precisely: it breaks at the \multicolumn, so as long as you don't use that it could *perhaps* work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Okay, If I have need `color rule` in `table` any other solution without `colortbl` package. The above `LaTeX` codeing in PDF display as `<Part>` tag. How to change or remove this tagging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

colortbl is currently not officially fully supported but the issue at hand has been fixed in version 2024/02/20 v1.0g which is already on ctan in a current texlive.

But be aware that there can be other open problems and do not ignore the messages in the log-file. If tagpdf spits out lots of warnings like

```
Package tagpdf Warning: Parent-Child 'Table/' --> 'TD/pdf2'.
(tagpdf)                Relation is not allowed (struct 40, /Table --> struct
(tagpdf)                41) on line 327
```

then that means that something in the structure it wrong!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. But, still `<PART>` tag is found in the tagged PDF. How to Remove or Change `<PART>` tag. Means it's coming `<PART><P>` and should needed only `<P>` or `<KAVI><P>`.

Comment: sorry but you shouldn't ask a bunch of question in one go. The site here should also help future users and that doesn't work if the questions get messy or additional answers are discussed in comments. Focus one question on one problem and keep your examples small. Remove unneeded text like an abstract or many tabular lines.  Beside this: the <Part><P> is by design. You can find some background in section 3 3 Tagging support of latex-lab-block.pdf.

Comment: Thanks a lot for `latex-lab-block.pdf` mentioned...

Comment: new colortbl has been sent to ctan @Kavi

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for your immediate action and now working fine with `colortbl` package and `\arrayrulecolor{green}\hline`...

Comment: @Kavi I always do what I'm told by Ulrike