Accessibility full check failed in Adobe DC for section head numbers and table caption Number which is tagged as <LBL>. How to rectify this issue
I have few queries listed below for the Accessibility check. could anyone help me to rectify the listed below issues.

In the tagged pdf, Section Numbers and Table caption numbers are tagged  as <LBL> tag. when run the Accessibility full check in Adobe DC showing error  (refer the screenshot below).



When using pdfversion=2.0,pdfstandard=ua-2 in the \DocumentMetadata, the PAC 2024 validator checker showing the below error (refer the below screenshot), when removed pdfversion=2.0,pdfstandard=ua-2, the pdf is passed for validating.



After removed pdfversion=2.0,pdfstandard=ua-2, the pdf is validating in the PAC 2024, but showing the validation error for the tables (refer the below screenshot)


Note: I am using TeXLive 2024 and Lualatex-dev
MWE:
\DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III,table},pdfversion=2.0,pdfstandard=ua-2,
uncompress}


\documentclass{article}


\tagpdfsetup{role/map-tags=pdf}
\begin{document}

\title{Sample title}

\maketitle

\section{A Head}

Sample text

\subsection{A Head}

Sample text11111111111111\footnote{222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222} 333333333333333333333333

\subsubsection{A Head}

Sample text

\paragraph{4th Level Head}

text

\subparagraph{5th Level Head}

text


\section{Another A Head}

Sample text

\begin{enumerate}
\item Fitst list item 
\item second list item 
\end{enumerate}

\begin{itemize}
\item Fitst list item 
\item second list item 
\end{itemize}


\tagpdfsetup{table-header-rows=1}
\begin{table}[!b]
\caption{Table Head}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\hline
THead 1 & THead2 & THead3\\
\hline
1 & 2 &3\\
4&5&6\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{bib01} bibligraphy item 1
\bibitem{bib02} bibligraphy item 2
\bibitem{bib03} bibligraphy item 3
\bibitem{bib04} bibligraphy item 4
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}


PAC doesn't like pdf 2.0 files. I already reported that, but you should do that too. Adobe doesn't like the (valid) use of  Lbl for the section numbers, complain to them that they should correct their checker. I would recommend to use a current verapdf to check the files, it can handle PDF 2.0, and it is regularly updated.

see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709655/2388

@UlrikeFischer thanks for the Swift reply
